# VB - Dealing with Negative Values

Tags: vb.net, negative-number

I am taking a beginning VB class and have just made my first program, a wage calculator with the added bonus of calculating the wages for overtime and doubletime, requiring the user to only enter hours worked and pay rate. So far it runs just as I designed with one flaw. If the user enters in less than 8 hours, I get a negative number in the amount of hours worked for OT which completely messes up the calculations for the wage. I thought putting in a conditional statement for the hours being less than or equal to zero would solve it, but it still prints and calculates a negative number.

Could someone be so kind as to point out what I am missing here? I'm sure it will be something simple that I haven't thought of.

Thank you in advance!

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim dblHoursWorked As Double = 0 'to hold hours worked
    Dim dblHourlyPayRate As Double = 0 'to hold hourly pay rate
    Dim dblStandardHours As Double = 0 'hold standard hours worked in a day which is always equal to 8
    Dim dblOtHours As Double = 0 ' to hold ot hours worked which is dblHoursWorked minus 8 then minus 4 if amount is greater than 4
    Dim dblOtCache As Double = 0 ' to hold variable for OT hours over 4
    Dim dblDtHours As Double = 0 'to hold dt hours worked which is ot hours minus 4 if ot is greater than 4
    Dim dblStandardPay As Double = 0 'to hold standard pay rate which is always <=8
    Dim dblOtPayRate As Double = 0 'to hold ot pay rate which is dblHourlyPayRate/2 + dblHourlyPayRate
    Dim dblDtPayRate As Double = 0 'to hold dt pay rate which is dblHourlyPayRate*2
    Dim dblOtPay As Double = 0 'Calcuate OT pay
    Dim dblDtPay As Double = 0 'Calculate DT pay
    Dim dblGrossPay As Double = 0 'to hold gross pay

    'making labels visible
    Label2.Visible = True
    Label6.Visible = True
    lblPrintOtRate.Visible = True
    lblPrintDtRate.Visible = True

    'Read the values from text box controls
    dblHoursWorked = CDbl(txtHoursWorked.Text)

    'Read value from text box controls
    dblHourlyPayRate = CDbl(txtPayRate.Text)

    'Calculate Standard Hours
    If dblHoursWorked >= 8 Then dblStandardHours = 8
    If dblHoursWorked < 8 Then dblStandardHours = dblHoursWorked

    'Display Standard Hours
    lblStandardHours.Text = CStr(dblStandardHours)

    'Calculate OT pay rate
    dblOtPayRate = dblHourlyPayRate / 2 + dblHourlyPayRate

    'calculate dt pay rate
    dblDtPayRate = dblHourlyPayRate * 2

    'Calculate OT hours cache
    dblOtCache = dblHoursWorked - 8

    'Conditional statement for OT hours if OT Cache calculations are below 0
    If dblOtCache <= 0 Then dblOtHours = Nothing

    'calculate ot hours actual if ot is equal to or less than 4
    If dblOtCache <= 4 Then dblOtHours = dblOtCache

    'conditional statements of what to print for ot hours if ot hours are greater than 4
    If dblOtCache > 4 Then dblOtHours = 4
    If dblOtCache > 4 Then dblDtHours = dblOtCache - 4

    'Display OT Hours worked
    lblOtHours.Text = CStr(dblOtHours)

    'Calculate DT Hours
    lblDtHours.Text = CStr(dblDtHours)

    'Calculate Standard Pay
    dblStandardPay = dblStandardHours * dblHourlyPayRate

    'Calculate OT Pay
    dblOtPay = dblOtPayRate * dblOtHours

    'Calculate DT Pay
    dblDtPay = dblDtPayRate * dblDtHours

    'Calculate Gross Pay
    dblGrossPay = dblStandardPay + dblOtPay + dblDtPay

    'Display Gross Pay
    txtTotalDailyPay.Text = "$ " + FormatNumber(CStr(dblGrossPay), 2)

    'Display OT Rate
    lblPrintOtRate.Text = "$ " + FormatNumber("$ " + CStr(dblOtPayRate), 2) + "  per hour"

    'Display OT Rate
    lblPrintDtRate.Text = "$ " + FormatNumber("$ " + CStr(dblDtPayRate), 2) + "  per hour"


End Sub
```

Comment: you need an IF to see if the total hours worked > 8 before this line: `dblOtCache = dblHoursWorked - 8`.  this would also be a great opportunity to learn to use the debugger

Comment: Like Plutonix said, Use the debugger and step through the code, I'm sure you'll be able to figure out the problem.If not post what you did and what you found.

Comment: not for nothing, but that is *a lot* of variables.  that makes it slightly more error prone to using the wrong one especially when they all start with `dbl`.

Comment: Thanks guys :)

I'll go back and add the new IF and see how that works. Will post the fixed code when I work it out.

Comment: @Plutonix, are there better ways for me to handle these variables to make it more stream-lined and less error prone? Is it just a matter of giving them a different starting abbreviation?

Comment: things like `dblOtPayRate` do not need their own variable especially when used just once per instance:  `OTPay = OTHours = (PayRate * 1.5)` will work just fine.  same for double time pay.  Using the var type as part of the var name is no longer in vogue because you can just hold the mouse over any variable to see what Type it is.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll clean that up as well before posting.

Comment: @Plutonix is referring to the Systems Hungarian notation, a knock-off of Apps Hungarian. If you're interested in naming practices, checking out the latter may be useful, since it would *not* suffer this particular problem, and is in fact designed so names make errors more obvious.

Comment: Don't allow the user to enter a negative value in the first place

Comment: that code snippet above should be `OTPay = OTHours * (PayRate * 1.5)` , sorry

Comment: This line:  `If dblOtCache <= 0 Then dblOtHours = Nothing` technically works in VB, but since `dblOtCache` is a value type, it may be clearer to write `If dblOtCache <= 0 Then dblOtHours = 0.0` instead.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone! Added the following two statements and got the result I was looking for:

 If dblHoursWorked < 8 Then dblOtCache = 0

 If dblHoursWorked >= 8 Then dblOtCache = dblHoursWorked - 8

@Plutonix also took your advice and cut out the Dtpayrate & Otpayrate variables and replaced with simple math.